# Spam Messages cb crond[1288]: No configuration file found at /root/.esmtprc or /etc/esmtprc

Tags: centos, cron, asterisk

Centos 8, fresh install
with asterisk on it
all log drains by one message 20-100 per sec

`cb crond[1288]: No configuration file found at /root/.esmtprc or /etc/esmtprc`

Answer (score 3):

Resolves by installing esmtp-local-delivery package from epel repo

```
dnf install esmtp-local-delivery
```

```
This packages contains the system ESMTP configuration file with local
delivery through an external mail delivery agent configured.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a `ddclient` default configuration file, but realized it was trying to mail error messages.  I disabled this line: `mail-failure=root`, showing that the error can be avoided if unnecessary instead of having more applications added.